# Hераспознанный параметр роли "IDENTIFIED" в PgAdmin 3

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql9.5, pgadmin

Здравствуйте скажите пожалуйста в чем заключается проблема того что PgAdmin 3 не понимает что такое "IDENTIFIED".

Вот мой запрос:

```
CREATE USER DEMO IDENTIFIED BY '123456789';
```

При запуске данного запроса выскакивает ошибка что нераспознанный параметр роли "IDENTIFIED". В чем заключается проблема ?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу его в описании https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createuser.html

Comment: `CREATE USER DEMO WITH PASSWORD '123456789'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что такого синтаксиса и [не существует](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createuser.html) в `PostgreSQL`

А вот использование странного тега натолкнуло на мысль - и, действительно, [в mysql именно такой синтаксис есть](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html).

Не нужно путать эти две СУБД. Как прямым текстом поясняет документация PostgreSQL,

> The SQL standard leaves the definition of users to the implementation.

Стандарт SQL оставляет всю кухню с созданием пользователей на усмотрение каждой конкретной СУБД. С такой вводной синтаксис, конечно, совместимым не получится.